# Do "creature crossings" do anything?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I was having Ignis drive me to my next quest destination when he suddenly stopped to let about 10 beasts run across the road and said "It seems we've reached a creature crossing," to which, Prompto asked "Where do you think they're going?" Gladiolus replied "Why don't we follow them and find out?" In my 56 hours of playtime, this is the first time I'd seen something like this, so it struck me as odd.

I ultimately chose not to bother following them, but should I have? Would I have found some valuable item or weapon if I'd chosen to follow the herd or was this just added flavor to spice up my drive?

Comment: I guess you must not drive much, I've seen them quite a few times. They seem to cross the street and just stop to mill about a bit.

Comment: @DavidYell nah I had been running everywhere to max out Survival but I finally caved and just banded my controllers overnight... so now I'm using the car :D

Comment: In my almost 65 hours of play, i have NEVER seen one of these. I started using fast travel really early though whenever i could as waiting for car rides became very tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Final Fantasy XV, the creature crossing are an aesthetic that means to breathe a degree of life into the world. As you noted Prompto posits where they may be headed and Gladio suggests following to find out.

Should you find the desire to satiate piqued curiosity, you'll find they simply cross the street and run into a nearby field where you can mercilessly slaughter and them for their horns just as you would had they not crossed the street and made you wait 30 more seconds before driving along the otherwise uneventful countryside.

So no... it doesn't "do" anything.